# java.io.IOException: Login failure for myuser@example.com from keytab

Tags: apache-spark, hbase, kerberos

I wrote a program by using spark streaming to insert data to kerberos enabled hbase. In one batch, I met one failed task. The error is below:

```
java.io.IOException: Login failure for myuser@example.com from keytab ./user.keytab
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytabAndReturnUGI(UserGroupInformation.java:1160)
    at com.framework.common.HbaseUtil$.InsertToHbase(HbaseUtil.scala:81)
    at com.framework.realtime.RDDUtil$$anonfun$dwsTodwd$2.apply(RDDUtil.scala:203)
    at com.framework.realtime.RDDUtil$$anonfun$dwsTodwd$2.apply(RDDUtil.scala:202)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$33.apply(RDD.scala:920)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$33.apply(RDD.scala:920)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1858)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1858)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:227)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Receive timed out
    at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.attemptAuthentication(Krb5LoginModule.java:767)
    at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.login(Krb5LoginModule.java:584)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor18.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:762)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:203)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:690)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:688)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:687)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:595)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytabAndReturnUGI(UserGroupInformation.java:1149)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out
    at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.receive0(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.receive(AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:146)
    at java.net.DatagramSocket.receive(DatagramSocket.java:816)
    at sun.security.krb5.internal.UDPClient.receive(NetClient.java:207)
    at sun.security.krb5.KdcComm$KdcCommunication.run(KdcComm.java:390)
    at sun.security.krb5.KdcComm$KdcCommunication.run(KdcComm.java:343)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.security.krb5.KdcComm.send(KdcComm.java:327)
    at sun.security.krb5.KdcComm.send(KdcComm.java:219)
    at sun.security.krb5.KdcComm.send(KdcComm.java:191)
    at sun.security.krb5.KrbAsReqBuilder.send(KrbAsReqBuilder.java:319)
    at sun.security.krb5.KrbAsReqBuilder.action(KrbAsReqBuilder.java:364)
    at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.attemptAuthentication(Krb5LoginModule.java:735)
    ... 25 more
```

But in the second attempt,the task succeed. In my opinion,the certification process is too long, so it fails, and in another attempt, the process is short. So it scceed. Am I correct? If so or not, how to solve this problem please?
My code is as below:

```
val ugi = UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytabAndReturnUGI(princ,
      keytab)

    ugi.doAs(new PrivilegedAction[Unit]() {
      def run(): Unit = {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        var conn: HConnection = null
        var htable: HTableInterface = null

          conn = HConnectionManager.createConnection(conf)
          htable = conn.getTable(tableName)
          htable.setAutoFlushTo(false)
          for (record <- partitionOfRecords) {
             htable.put(record)
          }
      }
    })
```

Comment: you can start by sharing the code producing the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From *[Hadoop and Kerberos - the Madness beyond the Gate](https://steveloughran.gitbooks.io/kerberos_and_hadoop/content/)* chapter *"Error Messages to Fear"*...

> ***Receive timed out***
>
> Usually in a stack trace like
>
> `Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out`
>   `at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.receive0(Native Method)`
>   `...`
>   `at sun.security.krb5.internal.UDPClient.receive(NetClient.java:207)`
>
> ... UDP socket ... Switch to TCP —at the very least, it will fail
>   faster.

And just above that:

> Switching kerberos to use TCP rather than UDP 
>   In `/etc/krb5.conf`:
>
> `[libdefaults]`
>   `udp_preference_limit = 1`

Generally speaking, many erratic Kerberos issues seem to occur only with UDP, so it's unfortunate that it's used by default...

---

Note that Java also supports **`kdc_timeout`** configuration parameter, but it's a dirty mess:

- not mentioned in [MIT Kerberos documentation](https://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-1.15/doc/admin/conf_files/krb5_conf.html)
- not mentioned in Unix/Linux documentation **except** [for BSD](https://www.daemon-systems.org/man/krb5.conf.5.html)
- mentioned only in the [darkest corners of Java documentation, here for Java 9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/security/kerberos-5-gss-api-mechanism.htm), with an interesting side note about the fact that the default value has changed from 30s-expressed-implicitly-in-milliseconds to 30s at some point
- a few weeks ago, the Cloudera support team issued a recommendation about that setting -- *because the 30s default timeout could create cascading failures in HDFS High Availability or something like that* -- but the poor guys did not really know what they were recommending, so they suggested randomly "3" or "3s" or "3000" for the explicit timeout value

---

Note also that if you have **multiple** KDCs for high availability, and these KDCs are explicitly listed in `krb5.conf` (or implicitly listed via a DNS alias set with a round-robin rule, for example) then in case of "KDC timeout" Java should retry with the next KDC in line. Unless you have reached a global time-out.